# porting linux on bare board

Tags: linux

Yesterday I faced with an *interview*. In *interview* he asked me for **steps to porting Linux on new board**. 
My answer was,

1. cross-compile u-boot for board architecture.
2. cross-compile kernel, with selecting driver for peripherals connected to board.
3. cross-compile filesystem, and port all on board.

But *Interviewer* is not happy with this answer.

Can you please suggest me which point were I missed out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you forgot the part where you actually write some software. If the board is new, then Linux and u-boot will not yet contain code to support the board. You must write that code.

Answer (score 0):

Porting steps -

- Install a cross-development environment.
- Setup the board and ensure that the serial port is working so we can print data through the serial port.
- Download and install the Linux kernel, most of the porting work will be done at this level.
- Add board specific code into the kernel tree.
- Build a kernel image to run on the board
- Test that early kernel printk is working
- Get the real printk working with the serial console.
- For a new board, a new board-specific directory should be added as well as support for interrupt handling, kernel timer services and mapping for memory areas.
- Ethernet drivers are usually the next drivers to focus on as they enable setup of NFS root file system to get access to user utilities and applications.
- Filesystem can be provided in different forms which are listed on LinuxFilesystem